WebDriverAgent 2 Sessions - One device
I'm trying to find a way to connect two appium services to one device which will allow me to run daily tests on the device, but meanwhile, have another session connect to that device and allow me to stream the screen to my app.
Basically the monitoring one allows me to send simple driver commands and what not to the device, as well as streams screenshots to my monitoring app. I need that to be up and running constantly on the device, but I want to start/stop tests on the same device while this monitoring driver runs. The issue I hit is that port 8100 needs to maintain its persistence so that both drivers can utilize it whenever they want.
I'm looking to see if anyone has any ideas on how to go about this?
